# Node,js ImageMagick conversion syntax question: How to apply multiple conversion methods?

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick

I am writing codes using Node.js to convert images that the users upload. Before, I only wrote codes for auto-rotation, but now I want to write codes also to compress them and to convert them to progressive JPEGs at one time.

Here is the code:

```
        return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
            return bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempLocalFile})
        }).then(() => {
            return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-auto-orient -quality 85 -interlace Plane', tempLocalFile])
        }).then(() => {
            metadata.autoOrient = true
            return bucket.upload(tempLocalFile, {
            destination: filePath,
            metadata: {metadata: metadata}
            })
        }).then(() => {
            fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile)
            console.log('Auto rotation, compression and PJPEG convsersion successful')
        })
```

The line that is causing the issue is the below one. When I use only '-auto-orient', it works fine. However, when I try to apply multiple methods, it fails.

```
    return spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-auto-orient -quality 85 -interlace Plane', tempLocalFile])
```

I guess this is a syntax problem...any advice on how to fix this code to do the jobs?

Comment: `'-auto-orient', '-quality', '85', '-interlace', 'plane'`

Comment: Cool - you can write it up as answer for all future visitors to see and accept it as correct and bag the points. I only made a comment because I was not at a machine to test.